# Spring bean creation is failing for beans without an "id" attribute

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring controller definition as follows :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/queue")
public class QueueController {

    QueuesService queueService;

    public QueueController(QueuesService queueService) {
        if (queueService == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("QueueService cannot be null");
        }
        this.queueService = queueService;
    }
}
```

And the corresponding entry in my context-configuration file is as follows (where the bean definition does not have any "id" attribute):

```
 <bean class="com.xy.web.controllers.QueueController">
<constructor-arg ref="queueServiceImpl"></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Now,during application startup, Spring is throwing below exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.xy.web.controllers.QueueController]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.xy.web.controllers.QueueController.<init>()
```

However when I add the "id" attribute to the "bean definition" (as follows), its getting created properly.

```
<bean id="queueController" class="com.xy.web.controllers.QueueController">
    <constructor-arg ref="queueServiceImpl"></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Any explanation for this or am I missing something here?

Comment: As a hint, try changing the `id` attribute to `asdasd`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm going to assume you have a `<content:component-scan ...>` in your config somewhere. This will try to instantiate any `@Component` annotated classes. `@Controller` is a `@Component` so Spring will try to instantiate `QueueController` using the class default empty constructor. In your case, such a constructor doesn't exist. Therefore it will throw the exception you are seeing.

You need to add an empty constructor

```
public QueueController() {}
```

This happens regardless of your bean declaration

```
<bean class="com.xy.web.controllers.QueueController">
    <constructor-arg ref="queueServiceImpl"></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

You're going to end up with two `QueueController` instances. This might not be what you want.

**As for the behavior you're seeing because of the id:**

When the application context reads the `component-scan` it will register a `BeanComponentDefinition` with name `queueController`. The context then moves on to your bean declaration. Because you've specified an `id` equal to the previous definition, it will override it. You will end up with only one bean definition for your `QueueController` class. Since the bean declaration requires a constructor with a specific argument and you have that, it won't complain and will create the bean.

If you specified a different `id`, say `abcd`, your application context would register two BeanDefinitions:  one with name `queueController` (following the default name generation strategy) from the `component-scan` and one with name `abcd` from the `<bean>` declaration. The `queueController` requires the default constructor which you don't have. You will therefore get an exception.

**More detailed**

If you are using a `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`, take a look at the `ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner#doScan(String...)` method's following call

```
String beanName = this.beanNameGenerator.generateBeanName(candidate, this.registry);
```

The `beanNameGenerator` is an instance of `AnnotationBeanNameGenerator`. It eventually calls

```
// Fallback: generate a unique default bean name.
return buildDefaultBeanName(definition, registry);
```

which calls

```
String shortClassName = ClassUtils.getShortName(definition.getBeanClassName());
return Introspector.decapitalize(shortClassName);
```

to return the default name `queueController`. That's the one you're `id` overrides.

You can actually see this in the logs:

```
Mon Aug 26 12:12:15 EDT 2013 [main] INFO  o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Overriding bean definition for bean 'queueController': replacing [Generic bean: class [org.test.QueueController]; scope=singleton; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in file [C:\Users\sotirios.delimanolis\git\content-store\target\test-classes\org\test\QueueController.class]] with [Generic bean: class [org.test.QueueController]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=0; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=null; factoryMethodName=null; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=null; defined in class path resource [app.xml]]
```